# Illegal Divide by Zero exception in cpp and C

Tags: c++, c

Here is a simple program which counts number of Individual digits that exactly divides given number.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long t, val, temp, count = 0, val1;
    scanf("%lld", &t);
    while (t--)
    {
        count = 0;
        scanf("%lld", &val);
        val1=val;
        while(val1 != 0)
        {
            temp = val1 % 10;
            val1 = val1 / 10.0 ;
            if (val % temp == 0)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        printf("%lld", count);
    }
}
```

It throws divide by zero exception when my input is

```
1
300
```

meaning number of test cases is 1 and value is 300.
But here I am dividing it by a constant 10 so why is that throwing that exception. So what should I do now to handle here?
*I even tried in cpp and faced same problem

Comment: Hint: use a debugger to confirm which line is causing the error.

Comment: This - `val % temp` - is also a division. And you are dividing by `temp`, which can easily be zero.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: What does that have to do with this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
val%temp
```

if `temp` is `0` (which seems to be the case in your program), you are invoking undefined behavior.